# Using Template Debugger with RSS

Tags: ee2, debugging

I have an RSS feed that's taking a long time to process and would like to use the Template Debugger to help me isolate which parts of it are consuming time. The problem is, all the Template Debugger output is HTMLized inside of the RSS template, so it's not rendering correctly. And if I set the page type from RSS to Web Page, well, then the RSS doesn't process right and I have nothing to debug. Is there a way to get the template debugger to at least output non-HTML text? That way I could pull the file with CURL and examine it.

Comment: How about pasting the html output into a .html file and viewing that in a browser?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wound up doing. Not the most convenient solution, but obviously not terrible, either. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the debug parameter to the feed itself https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/rss/#empty-feeds-and-errors

Comment: Unfortunately that pretty much does the same thing. It adds a bunch of HTML to the end of the feed that Firefox won't render because (a) it's after the </rss> tag and (b) it's HTML in a non-HTML file

Comment: one thing I usually do is wrap my custom fields in <![CDATA[ ]]> tags. How many entries are you trying to show at once?